# Display popup box via Powershell logon script

Tags: powershell

I know you can create powershell logon scripts and run them via Group Policy.  We have a requirement where we need the user to accept the IT Usage Policy and one way I thought of doing this would be to use a login script.  It would halt the login process and display a popup box after successfully logging in asking if they accept the policy (And requiring the OK/YES button to be pushed) before proceeding with login and taking the user to their desktop.  Is this possible?  If so, can it be set to either only run once or say every month?

If it is important, we exclusively run Windows 7 desktops.

Comment: Check this out: [Using Group Policy to Deploy a Windows PowerShell Logon Script](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/08/14/weekend-scripter-using-group-policy-to-deploy-a-windows-powershell-logon-script.aspx).

Comment: The built in Domain EULA pre-login isn't good enough?

Comment: I've never heard of a Domain EULA before.

Comment: Print the IT Usage Policy on a sheet of paper and have the employee/contractor sign it. Problem solved. Legally effective, too.

Comment: Makes too much sense, trust me.  The issue is ensuring that no one is missed and giving users constant reminders so 3 years after they signed it they don't whinge when we've been monitoring their usage.  Yes, it is legally binding so we won't have issues there, but there is staff management to consider as well as legality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is Yes.  Here is a link to an example [Provide a Yes/No Prompt in Windows PowerShell](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/1a386b01-b1b8-4ac2-926c-a4986ac94fed)
Along with the link posted by @neolisk you should be able to cover off both sides of your question.

```
    $a = new-object -comobject wscript.shell 
    $intAnswer = $a.popup("Do you want to choose Yes or No?", 0,"Confirmation",4)
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work when you execute the script as "logon one". There should be a costrain that inhibit the appears of messageboxes.